# What does R(C::*)(P1,P2) mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I saw this template declaration:

```
template<typename C, typename R, typename P1, typename P2> struct mystruct<R(C::*)(P1,P2)> { ... };
```

I know that C::* means "a pointer to a member of C", but I can't understand what the R(C::*)(P1,P2) does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the type passed to the template parameter of `mystruct` is a pointer to a member function of `C` with a return type of `R` which takes two parameters of types `P1` and `P2`.

Answer (score 8):

```
R(C::*)(P1,P2)
```

Pointer to a member function of class C, taking parameters of types P1 and P2, returning R.

The line as a whole is a class template specialization (there has to exist at least a declaration of a primary template for `mystruct` somewhere).

Answer (score 5):

`R(C::*)(P1,P2)` means pointer to function which is member of C return R and takes P1 and P2 as arguments.